# 2021 Moderator Election - Ballot doesn't work

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-election

When I try to vote in [the election](/election), the drag & drop does not work.  I have tried several places in the candidate boxes but the best I get is this, where it somehow wants to drag multiple names:

[image]

I also tried the click method, but that did nothing (no names would be selected).

I do have dark mode selected, so I went to my profile to switch it to light in case that would make a difference.  That wouldn't save though, so I am stuck in dark mode and cannot test the other way.

One error in the dev console when first loading the page:
[image]

Browser: Chrome Version 94.0.4606.81 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Did you try to click the names and move them up?

Comment: Have you got any userscripts, adblockers, extensions etc. running?

Comment: @JeanneDark I tried the names, the avatars, the 6 dots, and several spots in the black spaces around the names.

Comment: @Nick - No user scripts.  My browser does have some corporate management thing on it but I have never seen it interfere with any website functions before.

Comment: Maybe it's because you are trying to vote for the wrong candidates? Try voting for the right ones, it will probably work then. /s

Comment: Are there any errors in the Developer Tools' console? I can't reproduce it with the same browser/version (also using dark mode).

Comment: Do you have [JavaScript disabled](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/disable/)?

Comment: to second StephenOstermiller, do you see [this giant warning message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40GHN.png) by any chance?

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm seeing this same behavior.  I have JavaScript enabled, Google Chrome Version 94.0.4606.81 (Official Build) (x86_64), both macOS 11.6 and Pop!_OS Linux 21.04, and, although I have Privacy Badger installed, I get the same thing even if I disable it for the site.

Comment: I'm experiencing all kinds of JavaScript failures on SO since yesterday (comments, flagging, etc.). I came to Meta looking for a general conversation about that. Haven't found it yet. Updated Chrome on Windows. I use uBlock Origin, but it's disabled for  SO.

Comment: No, javascript is not disabled.

Comment: @Ivar  I added a screenshot of the dev console.

Comment: FWIW I've pinged the member of staff who reported the fix for a similar issue yesterday as this seems heavily related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370955/review-queues-not-working-because-of-javascript-error#comment1238317_370963

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem (latest version of Firefox, no add-ons). I came here looking for this question.

Comment: We're hoping to ship a fix for this shortly. Thanks for your patience! Apologies for the democracy fail. :)

Comment: Mind reloading the page and trying again?

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson  It works for me now.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looks like you were the victim of [an especially stubborn cache](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/370963/312922). I've pushed out a new version which *should* result in a refreshed cache for all users. *Should*.

Thanks again for reporting this, and sorry for the inconvenience.