# Add/Show Comment jumps back to the top of the page

Tags: bug, status-completed

"Add a comment" or "Show more comments" link does not work properly. It jumps back to the top of the page instead of adding or showing the comments.

Example link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69631586/calculating-handling-time-out-of-overlapping-intervals#)

Comment: This usually happens if the page did not load all scripts. Do you use something like `noscript` or have a slow/unstable connection?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the developer console? There was an issue yesterday that was theoretically fixed.

Comment: This happened to other people yesterday. [It was mentioned in the election chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/238039?m=53270202#53270202)

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thanks for you comment. No, I didn't use anything like `noscript`. And I believed my internet connection is quite stable. It works properly until today morning.

Comment: @JackGorBeatCo Several people seems to have problems with scripts today, e.g. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412373/2021-moderator-election-ballot-doesnt-work#comment874062_412373

Comment: MSE post on issue: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370955/review-queues-not-working-because-of-javascript-error

Comment: @isherwood How would you know if those are related?

Comment: The JavaScript error is the same (or similar), and the answer on the question Nick linked explains it all.

Comment: (or similar).. :O  "Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null" doesn't strike me as being definitely the same error. It's just the same symptom. One could be fixed while the other is untouched.

Comment: @isherwood Are you aware that the meta.stackexchange post that was the cause of the other one is status-completed?

Comment: The bottom line is that there are already many discussions happening about this event as a whole. Fragmenting it further won't help. If you don't agree, don't vote to close. I'm out.

Comment: @isherwood yes I agree. It does seem like all these are the same issue.

Comment: Mind reloading the page and trying again?

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson it works now! Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you were the victim of [an especially stubborn cache](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/370963/312922). I've pushed out a new version which *should* result in a refreshed cache for all users. *Should*.

Thanks again for reporting this, and sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Thank you. Commenting, comment flagging, and dynamic header icons are all working again on SO for me after clearing cache.

Comment: It seems that this has also solved my problem (which co-occurred for me with this problem.) https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/370974/170190