# Recent achievements menu redirecting

Tags: bug, reputation

On iOS 15 and Safari 15 on [macOS v11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Big_Sur) (Big Sur) and on the main site only, the achievements trophy icon is redirecting me to my Stack Exchange user profile, instead of presenting the pop over menu.

I am getting

```
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementById("webpack-public-path").innerText')
```

I am not sure if it’s related.

It might be related as well - on the main site I do not get the ability to expand the vote tallies - probably due to this script erroring out.

Later I forced Safari to ignore its cache and things are loading fine with a clean copy.

Comment: The page has loaded completely afaik

Comment: Safari, BigSur, cannot reproduce. But there are several users complaining about "random" JS errors on more fronts today. E.g. see [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/412377/1426539) or [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/412373/1426539).

Comment: Looks like the same issue as [Cannot post a question](/q/412340/4642212).

Comment: MSE duplicate of [Review queues not working because of JavaScript error](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/370955/818993) - clearing cache solves the issue, as mentioned in the question after edit.